# How do I pass a dataframe to a Function class to store as a member for transformation use?

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a transformation class, someFunction(Dataframe df), that I want to use another dataframe with. But when I try to access it during transformation, everything within the dataframe is null (LogicalPlan and everything else is null within the dataframe). Is there a way I can do this?

Edit:

```
SparkStreamFlatMapFunction flatMap = new SparkStreamFlatMapFunction(DF);

JavaDStream<DataFrame> words = transaction.flatMap(flatMap);
```

StreamFlatMapFunction

```
public SparkStreamFlatMapFunction(DataFrame DF) {
        this.DF = DF;
    }

@Override
public Iterable<DataFrame> call(String arg0) throws Exception {
        DF.show();
}
```

I get null pointer exception because all the values in DF are null.

Comment: Could you provide some example what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I posted an example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, in Spark you can't reference another RDD (or DataFrame) inside of the transformation or action on another RDD (or DataFrame). The normal ways of supporting these types of operations are either joining the two DataFrames together, or if one of the two DataFrame's is small enough collecting the data into a regular Java/Scala collection and then using `broadcast` (or skipping broadcast) and referencing that collection. Sometimes in addition to join crossproducts can be used to achieve the desired result. Since you haven't posted exactly what it is you are trying to do this is a pretty general answer but looking at `PairRDDFunctions` will maybe give you some idea for the possible solutions. Best of luck with your Spark adventures :)